# how can I see the javascript code that affected the HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We can see the css that is used in an html element upon inspect element, how can I see the javascript/jquery for it? I want to modify some templates' javascript/jquery, extract it piece by piece  and learn from it

Comment: In your chrome devtools you have the **Sources** tab. Where you can press **CTRL+O** to open your JS files being referenced in your HTML page, and you can even you put breakpoints there to check the flow

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firefox, try Firebug extension.